# Cross OS SW - what would be the differences of different type of linux

Tags: linux, validation, operating-system

I have same product - same source code that is compiled and targted for differetn operating systems on same platform.
e.g. 1. several types of linux image / android/ linux
and trying to understand what do I need to duplicate when validating and what wouldn't change between the OS
Currently I assume the performance may vary but what else?
are there existing researches / data about modifications and risk taking on multi OS?

Comment: Does your code compile and run on each OS you're targeting? If you don't get errors (i.e. `API X is not supported on this system` type of errors), then it shouldn't result in any oddities beyond performance ... Are you getting any errors between builds or run-time errors between OS's?

Comment: yes my code compiles on both.I know performance can be different 1. are there any type of statistics or researches on this? 2. what about scheduler that may be different between OS or anything else?